# Would it be possible to put italics in the titles?

Tags: feature-request

Sometimes I really feel that titles with italics could be more readable, specially when one wants to stress the German word one asks about. To me, using quoting marks sometimes is not enough (or it doesn't have a nice appearance).

Comment: Do you have examples?

Answer (score 6):

I'm afraid that the question title field of posts in the StackExchange database is interpreted as text field, not as "rich text" (HTML) and therefore doesn't accept formatting.